# HTML elements and inline CSS in text fields

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to find ways to customize a website where I can only edit the content (text and image) via Contentful’s content management interface (the company that developed the website refuses to integrate the corporate identity and style guide and says it "might" be for future versions).

What do you think about adding HTML elements, inline CSS, or even adding style and loading fonts via style elements directly into the text fields? Given that these elements will obviously be in the middle of the body, is this really bad practice in terms of security and SEO (or other)?

Thank you a lot for your time.

Comment: it's just hard to mantain and it may result in weird styling flashing at load in case those new styles collide with the external styles that will be ready few instants later. It's usually  recommended to keep both style and link tags in the head for those reasons. Nowadays the mdn page says: _"The <style> element **must be** included inside the <head> of the document. In general, it is better to put your styles in external stylesheets and apply them using <link> elements"_. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style

Comment: Thank you very much! Hopefully, they will consider adding some custom files. If not, what if I create some sort of fake empty element with just a style element as text that I place at the top of each page? Would that be significantly better?

Comment: maybe you didn't get the whole picture. It's still somehow legit to use style elements wrapping css rules anywhere in the dom. Strictly speaking it won't be perfectly html5 valid but yet functional. But if you have css rules everywhere in the page it will be hard to deal with them in the long term. Plus the FOUT (flash of unstyled text) might happen if a rule in your "floating" styles is overlapping with rules coming from external css that will be ready after they have been fetched (in case there's the async defer behaviour).

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear (and asking the right question apparently). I can definitely see how hard it is going to maintain (I don't even use CSS frameworks usually because I don't like mixing HTML and CSS so...). I just wanted to make sure I wasn't making a huge mistake by choosing to do this because I've been asked to make something beautiful with very few possibilities. Thank you a lot for your precious time! If any other (magic) solution comes to your mind, I'd be happy to hear about it.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say it's bad for security since it's just style (meaning how the users see the website).

Have you thought about linking the style file? It would maybe be a cleaner solution (don't forget you will have to maintain it later, and having it in a clear way will save you a lot of time reading and wondering what you did, so it's better to be clean) than adding everything inline inside body

As for SEO I believe it's more affected by the use of the elements than having the elements. I mean, if you want some content use  instead of a  tag that resembles by style to a heading.

Comment: I am indeed considering asking them to add my own style file to overload the current style but I'm not sure they will be ok with it and I might still be limited in some ways (as, for example, some titles are not even in heading elements but just divs). Thank you for your answer!